# Parse AngularJS client errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logging, error-handling

I'm trying to format AngularJS `$log` errors and send them to the server.  My problem is I cannot figure out how to get the data.

Check out this fiddle to see my decorator in action.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/777/)

What I'm having a hard time with is getting the desired data out from the first element in the array.  It says the type is an object but when I try to iterate over the object I get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code isn't actually using the $log service. You have to use `try{} catch(e){}` to catch the error and then use `$log.error(e)` for that.
I've modified the fiddle.
Please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/779/

Hope this helps. Thanks

EDIT:

The issue is that you're trying to iterate over an Error object :) it doesn't behave same as a normal object.
If you want the data, you'll have to use obj.message and obj.stack respectively.
Check my updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/787/

Comment: Okay, I can't see what you modified there. I'm not sure how that helps me parse the object to get the data I want.

Comment: @tester123 .. Updated my answer.. Do check the fiddle.

Comment: Yes that helps! Thanks, your edits are much more clear